# how to import data from a csv file into a 2 dimensional array in VB.NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net, csv

I have some data stored in a csv in the following format:

```
username,info1,info2,info3
username2,info1,info2,info3
username3,info1,info2,info3
username2,info1,info2,info3
```

The same username can appear more than once.

I would like to read this into a 2D array so that `0, 0` would be `username` and `2, 1` would be `info1`.

I would use the split function, but I want a 2D array rather than a lot of 1D arrays.

Comment: The Split function can be used to create a 2d array, nesting two For each loops, one split by " " (space character) and the other one split by ",". Anyways, since you don't know your array's length (the csv file can have different data, I guess), you could do this with lists instead of arrays

Comment: I would definitely suggest a list of arrays. Use split on each line to create the array for that line, but then just use Add on the list so you don't have to know the size ahead of time. Just be aware that Split by itself won't work if any of your values are quoted strings that may have commas in them.